# Set default shell in Cloud9 Terminal

Tags: cloud9-ide

I've installed zsh in the Terminal and set it to be my default shell but I'm still logged in running bash.  I even get this in a SSH Project to my remote server where zsh is my login shell.  What setting in C9 do I have to change?

Comment: what version of linux? how did you set it to be the default shell, through a variable or script?

Comment: The Terminal shell runs C9's version of Ubuntu.  My remote server runs Debian Wheezy.  In both cases /etc/passwd has /usr/bin/zsh in the shell field for the logged in user as set by chsh.

Comment: maybe try a init script to chsh?

Comment: also did you run it as root?

Comment: It seems something in the C9 environment is overriding the linux VM's own configuration.  After all, my login shell is set correctly when I ssh to my remote server directly.  It's not a big deal since I can always just run zsh manually but I'm hoping there's C9 setting or preference I can change.

Comment: To StackOverflow moderator: This question relates only to Cloud9 IDE, an online programming environment.  It is not about server administration in general.

Comment: Or you could install Oh My Zsh (with sudo) https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out! It seems C9 runs our login sessions under tmux which has its own default shell command setting = bash.  I created my own tmux.conf with the line "set -g default-command zsh", ran "unset TMUX" to disable the inherited tmux settings, ran tmux and got a nice tmux session with the usual green menu bar and with zsh as the default shell.

Comment: where did you placed the .tmux.config? it isn't loaded if it's in home directory of the executing user

Comment: @SeriousM: my ~/.tmux.conf is loaded fine.

Comment: Or you could install Oh My Zsh (with sudo) https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Comment: But when you switch shells the SSH keys stop working it seems ): and mouse srrolling doesn't work on zsh. Stuck with bash.